# Min/Max of two variables Hibernate SQL

Tags: sql, hibernate, max, hsqldb, min

How can i select the minimum of two variables in hsql query language?

I need something like `"select ... as x ... as y.... where min(x,y) <= value"`

The `min()` and `max()` functions apply only to column values.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably mean the LEAST value:

```
SELECT LEAST(x , y) FROM MYTABLE
SELECT X, Y FROM MYTABLE WHERE LEAST(X,Y) <= value 
SELECT X, Y FROM MYTABLE WHERE X <= value OR Y <= value /* this is more efficient */
```

You can select the minimum value among the LEAST values of the two variables in a row:

```
SELECT MIN(LEAST(x , y)) FROM MYTABLE
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometime we simply ignore the simple ways to do things and make them complicated.

Looking at your query it seems you are filtering the rows whose two columns values are less than some variable.

You may use query like this:

```
SELECT... AS x ... AS y.... WHERE x <= value AND y <= value
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes, this might be a solution for my initial question but unfortunately I cannot apply it in my specific scenario. The example I posted was somewhat a high level view on the problem. It might have been my fault for not offering a more detailed view.

Comment: @MirceaMan - Your problem is solved and that matters cheers for that. On a side not please take some time and edit your query and add the missing details so that future users who come searching similar issue can be benefited.